# Apache 2.4 не получается запустить мой проект, запускает дефолтную страницу апача

Tags: php, apache, laravel, apache2, apache2.4

На данный момент:
права у папки drwxrwxrwx

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName test.laravel.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot   var/www/projects/test.laravel.com
```

Прописано в хостах: 127.0.0.1 test.laravel.com

В файле apache2.conf:

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/projects/test.laravel.com/public>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Загвоздка была не в конфигах, они ВСЕ правильные, а в использовании утилиты a2ensite.

Comment: Распишите ответ более конкретно. В чём именно была проблема? Как вы её исправили и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

Точка входа в Ларавель /public/index.php 
Собственно надо прописать правильно директорию 
var/www/projects/test.laravel.com/public/

```
<Directory /var/www/projects.test.laravel.com/public/>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: ситуация не изменилась...(

Comment: Давайте сделаем немного проще :
1) cd etc/apache2/sites-available/
2) touch test.laravel.conf
3) вставляем  <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName test.laravel.com
   ServerAlias www.test.laravel.com
   ServerAdmin admin@admin.com
   DocumentRoot  /var/www/projects/test.laravel.com/public
        <Directory /var/www/projects/test.laravel.com/public>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
                    Require all granted
                    AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
4) a2ensite test.laravel.conf
5) apache reload